# Rolemanager not working properly

Tags: c#, roles

My rolemanager in c# is not working as I want it to.

When starting my site, an loggin page is started. And when logged in, redirects you to Default.aspx

```
var username = (string)Session["username"];
    Login1.LoggedIn += (ee, ff) =>
    {            
        Session.Add("username", Login1.UserName);  
        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
}
```

My masterpage checks if session is `null` then go to Login.aspx

```
if (Session["username"] == null)
{
Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
return;
}`
```

I have 2 diffrent roles "admin" and "vip".

So if the user is in the role "admin" grant access to the specific aspx site else dont!.

```
     if (User.IsInRole("admin"))
       {
          Response.Redirect("Test.aspx");
      } else if (User.IsInRole("vip")) {
         Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
       }`
```

Still it does not matter who is logged in, it still grants access to Test.aspx

My webconfig file:

```
<system.web>
  <authorization>
   <allow roles="admin" />
  </authorization>`
```

Hope someone is understands my "small" problem

Answer (score 1):

try giving deny users also in web.config like :

```
<system.web>
<authorization>
<allow roles="admin" />
<deny users="*" />
</authorization>`
```

Comment: Been trying that. it denies my whole project. Access is denied.

Comment: How are adding the users to their corresponding roles?? If u r adding through the website administration tool, then enable the role management in web.config like :  `<roleManager enabled="true">` under system.web and then use condition like :                      `if (HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Admin"))` to check  whether the user belongs to the this role or not.